# Read CSV sheet data and created new one

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file which have multiple sheets in it. Want to read it sheet by sheet and filter some data and want to create csv file in same format. how can I do that. Please suggest. I was trying it though pandas.ExcelReader but its not working for CSV file.

Comment: check pandas read_csv

Comment: Hi, since you're new, please always post a reproducable example and some code you tried with each questions. Also, AFAIK, csv files do not support sheets so you can treat a CSV file as a single sheet

Comment: if you created this CSV then better change code which create this CSV and write every sheet in separated file because `csv` is only to keep single sheet/table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following code for this may help!

```
import pandas as pd

def read_excel_sheets(xls_path):
    """Read all sheets of an Excel workbook and return a single DataFrame"""
    print(f'Loading {xls_path} into pandas')
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(xls_path)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    columns = None
    for idx, name in enumerate(xl.sheet_names):
        print(f'Reading sheet #{idx}: {name}')
        sheet = xl.parse(name)
        if idx == 0:
            # Save column names from the first sheet to match for append
            columns = sheet.columns
        sheet.columns = columns
        # Assume index of existing data frame when appended
        df = df.append(sheet, ignore_index=True)
    return df
```

the resource for this code is the link below:

[click here](https://www.codegrepper.com/search.php?answer_removed=1&q=how%20to%20read%20csv%20with%20multiple%20sheet%20in%20pandas%20with%20python)

and for converting it back to csv you can follow the post which link is
[attached here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-export-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-2038e43d9c03)